# How can I use ALSA dmix and multi plugins together?

Tags: audio, alsa

I'm playing with [a console sound visualiser](https://github.com/karlstav/cava) which wants its own ALSA device to listen on. I'm editing `~/.asoundrc`. I know I'll need the `multi` [plugin](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html) to split the sound data onto separate devices. However, my soundcard has no hardware mixing, so I'll also need a `dmix` plugin in there somewhere, for software mixing.

If I try to add a `multi` as a slave of the `dmix`, I get this error <sub>(line-wrapped)</sub>:

```
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:1525:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset)
Invalid type 'multi' for slave PCM
```

I tried creating a "dummy middleman" `plug` with the `multi` as a slave, and pointing the `dmix` to *that*, but still get the same error. Looks like `dmix` wants the whole chain of stuff to be `plug` or `hw`…

If I try to add a `dmix` module as a slave of a `multi` instead, I get

```
Device or resource busy
```

As you'd expect when software mixing isn't the first step in the pipeline, but multiple programs try to grab the sound card.

Both of these things (`dmix`ing, and `multi`-ing to a loopback device) work well separately.

Why do `dmix` and `multi` not work together? How can I make this work?

---

Here's my `~/.asoundrc`, with options that give *Invalid type 'multi' for slave PCM*:

```
# thx
# http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/.asoundrc
# http://alsa.opensrc.org/Dmix
# http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=196&t=94877

pcm.snd_card {
    type hw
    card 1
    device 0
}

# allows multiple programs to output sound simultanously ("software mixing")
pcm.dmixer {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    ipc_perm 0666 # allow other users
    slave.pcm "out"
    slave {
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        ### if having problems
        # rate 44100
        ### some sound cards need the exact data format
        # format S32_LE
        ### Available formats: S8 U8 S16_LE S16_BE U16_LE U16_BE S24_LE S24_BE
        ###                    U24_LE U24_BE S32_LE S32_BE U32_LE U32_BE
        ###                    FLOAT_LE FLOAT_BE FLOAT64_LE FLOAT64_BE
        ###                    IEC958_SUBFRAME_LE IEC958_SUBFRAME_BE MU_LAW
        ###                    A_LAW IMA_ADPCM MPEG GSM
        channels 2 # must match bindings
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}

# allows multiple programs to capture simultaneously
pcm.dsnooper {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 2048
    ipc_perm 0666 
    slave.pcm "snd_card"
    slave 
    {
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        channels 2 
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}

pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "dmixer"
    capture.pcm "dsnooper"
}

pcm.out {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type multi
        slaves {
            a { channels 2 pcm "snd_card" }
            b { channels 2 pcm "hw:Loopback,0,0" }
        }
        bindings {
            0 { slave a channel 0 }
            1 { slave a channel 1 }
            2 { slave b channel 0 }
            3 { slave b channel 1 }
        }
    }
    ttable [
        [ 1 0 1 0 ]   # left  -> a.left,  b.left
        [ 0 1 0 1 ]   # right -> a.right, b.right
    ]
}

# In case I ever want to use PulseAudio, for bluetooth speakers or such.
#pcm.!default {
#    type pulse
#}
#ctl.!default {
#    type pulse
#}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out each output device needs its own `dmix`:

```
[!default] → multi → dmix → hw [normal]
                   ↳ dmix → hw [loopback]
```

I was missing a second `dmix` between the `multi` and loopback-`hw`, so although my usual card would have been fine, the loopback card had no mixing.

Many thanks to [CL.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/23071/cl) for patience and expertise.

---

For the technical details, here's my `~/.asoundrc` now:

```
pcm.snd_card { # my usual sound card
    type hw
    card 2
}

ctl.!default { # default control; alsamixer and such will use this
    type hw
    card 2
}

# software mixer for sound card
pcm.dmixer {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    ipc_perm 0666 # allow other users
    slave.pcm "snd_card"
    slave {
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        channels 2 # must match bindings
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}

# software mixer for loopback device
pcm.dmixerloop {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 2048
    ipc_perm 0666 # allow other users
    slave.pcm "hw:Loopback,0,0"
    slave {
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        channels 2 # must match bindings
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}

# allows multiple programs to capture simultaneously
pcm.dsnooper {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 2048
    ipc_perm 0666 
    slave.pcm "snd_card"
    slave 
    {
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        channels 2 
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}

pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "out"
    capture.pcm "dsnooper"
}

# Multi, splitting onto usual card and loopback
pcm.out {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type multi
        slaves {
            a { channels 2 pcm "dmixer" }
            b { channels 2 pcm "dmixerloop" }
        }
        bindings {
            0 { slave a channel 0 }
            1 { slave a channel 1 }
            2 { slave b channel 0 }
            3 { slave b channel 1 }
        }
    }
    ttable [
        [ 1 0 1 0 ]   # left  -> a.left,  b.left
        [ 0 1 0 1 ]   # right -> a.right, b.right
    ]
}
```