# Using ALSA with dmix and multi plugins together for recording

Tags: alsa, ffmpeg, alsamixer

I'm trying to set up ALSA for recording some videos with ffmpeg, so I need to both hear the application sound and be able to record it (I actually probably need to record 1 specific application). Recording microphone is not so important, but there's not even any problem with it, it works fine. I only have a built-in soundcard, no external ones (though there's some audio device that's added by my Nvidia graphics card). I'm editing `~/.asoundrc`. I tried to use the guide from ffmpeg wiki, but that didn't really work for me, it didn't use dmix, thus only allowing 1 application playing sound at a time. Also, for some reason it didn't even record the sound of this application. I don't remember why as I ditched this solution due to only being able to hear 1 application. Then I stumbled upon [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194547/how-can-i-use-alsa-dmix-and-multi-plugins-together) question here. I copied the solution to this question (of course I've changed default card accordingly), and now my `~/.asoundrc` looks like this:

```
pcm.snd_card { # my usual sound card
    type hw
    card 1
}

ctl.!default { # default control; alsamixer and such will use this
    type hw
    card 1
}

# software mixer for sound card
pcm.dmixer {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1
    slave.pcm "snd_card"
    slave {
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        channels 2 # must match bindings
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}

# software mixer for loopback device
pcm.dmixerloop {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 2
    slave.pcm "hw:Loopback,0,0"
    slave {
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        channels 2 # must match bindings
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}

# allows multiple programs to capture simultaneously
pcm.dsnooper {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 2
    slave.pcm "snd_card"
    slave 
    {
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        channels 2 
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}

pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "out"
    capture.pcm "dsnooper"
}

# Multi, splitting onto usual card and loopback
pcm.out {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type multi
        slaves {
            a { channels 2 pcm "dmixer" }
            b { channels 2 pcm "dmixerloop" }
        }
        bindings {
            0 { slave a channel 0 }
            1 { slave a channel 1 }
            2 { slave b channel 0 }
            3 { slave b channel 1 }
        }
    }
    ttable [
        [ 1 0 1 0 ]   # left  -> a.left,  b.left
        [ 0 1 0 1 ]   # right -> a.right, b.right
    ]
}
```

This worked, but not perfectly. The problem is, I am able to record sound from applications and microphone, but applications are too silent, I can barely hear an app at my normal conditions (Master set to -5dB in alsamixer, volume in application itself set to 75%) and this doesn't really get much better even if I turn up the volume in both alsamixer and app to 100%. Microphone on the other hand has normal volume. I also get a strange error when type `alsactl restore` in terminal:

```
alsa-lib main.c:1560:(snd_use_case_mgr_open) error: failed to import hw:2 use case configuration -2
```

I figured that this has to do with Loopback device, but I'm not sure what that means. I'm also not sure if that even has something to do with volume of applications. Is that error important? Does it have effect on the volume? How do I fix volume of the applications?

EDIT: I switched to configuration from ffmpeg wiki and this one couple of times. After a reboot alsamixer has Master set to 46% and I'm not able to change it for some reason. My slstatus (gets info from amixer) on the other hand shows 92%, which is what I set it to previously (-5dB). It is also worth noting that with this configuration microphone doesn't work with Discord and Steam Voice Chat, even though their configuration hasn't changed a bit. I'm also not able to hear any sounds from Discord, and, I guess, Steam Voice Chat too. I'm still able to record microphone sound with ffmpeg though. I'm also able to hear other applications like firefox or games.

EDIT: It appears that I was wrong, I can hear sounds from both Discord and Steam Voice Chat. Though Steam is able to capture my microphone properly whereas Discord isn't.

EDIT: I'm not sure if that's how it's supposed to work (it probably is), but when I turn off capturing my microphone in alsamixer there's nothing being recorded at all.